# Weird redirect with proxy_pass in if statement

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, nginx

I've a SPA (Single Page Application) site, let's say under https://example.com and an API for it under https://api.example.com

I want to serve server rendered content for specific useragents like `googlebot`, `facebookexternalhit`, etc.

So, if user goes to https://example.com/brandon/things it will get served SPA, but if bot goes to the same URL it will get served server rendered page with all proper meta and open graph tags.

My server rendered pages with proper matching are under https://api.example.com/ssr/

So for example if bot hits https://example.com/brandon/things it should get content from https://api.example.com/ssr/brandon/things

I almost got it working with nginx proxy_pass if statement to the Django application (which returns server rendered output) but unfortunately there's one edge case that makes it behave weirdly.

---

My implementation:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com; # url of SPA 
    index index.html;

    root /srv/example_spa/public/dist; # directory of SPA index.html


    # $ssr variable that tells if we should use server side rendered page

    set $ssr 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|facebot|twitterbot|developers\.google\.com|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|redditbot") {
        set $ssr 1;
    }


    # location block that serves proxy_pass when the $ssr matches
    # or if the $ssr doesn't match it serves SPA application index.html

    location / {

        if ($ssr = 1) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9505/ssr$uri$is_args$args;
        }

        try_files $uri /index.html;

    }


}
```

---

**But there's the problem:**

Everything works dandy and sweet, except one case.

User hits `https://example.com/brandon/things/` and he gets SPA index.html - perfect.

User hits `https://example.com/brandon/things` and he gets SPA index.html - perfect.

Bot hits `https://example.com/brandon/things/` and he gets server rendered page - perfect.

Bot hits `https://example.com/brandon/things` (without appended slash) and he gets redirected (301) to `https://example.com/ssr/brandon/things` - BAD BAD BAD

---

I've tried to make it work for couple of hours now without luck.
 What would you suggest? I know if in nginx is evil, but I don't know how to make it work without it...

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the redirects for `proxy_pass`

```
location / {
    proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1/ssr/ http://$host/ssr/;
    proxy_redirect /ssr/ /;

    if ($ssr = 1) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9505/ssr$uri$is_args$args;
    }

    try_files $uri /index.html;

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I've actually found a solution next day, and I've added it here. The problem didn't lied in nginx, but my application redirects.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was issue with my Django application redirect. I thought I had "APPEND_SLASH" option disabled, but it was enabled and made redirect when there was no slash. And it redirected without changing the host to https://api.example.com, but only URI part. Hence my confusion.

And I actually found two ways to fix that.

---

**First**, just use rewrite to append slash when there isn't one.

```
location / {

    if ($ssr = 1) {
        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9505/ssr$uri$is_args$args;
    }

    try_files $uri /index.html;

}
```

---

**Second**, modify proxy_pass to always add / slash after $uri part and server side render application url config to accept two slashes at the end //'. It's a little hacky but has no side effects and works as it should.

Nginx config:

```
location / {

    if ($ssr = 1) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9505/ssr$uri/$is_args$args;
    }

    try_files $uri /index.html;

}
```

Django URL regex:

```
r'^ssr/(?P<username>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)(/|//)$'
```